# Unable to ssh into compute engine instance using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I've installed GCP's cloud SDK on Mac and I have owner's role and I am trying to ssh into one of the compute engine instances using this command.

```
gcloud compute ssh user@instance-name
```

Unfortunately I am getting an error. Here is the output that I am getting on executing that command.

```
External IP address was not found; defaulting to using IAP tunneling.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Error while connecting [[Errno 1] Operation not permitted].
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Strangely, I am able to ssh into the instance using cloud shell. So I think IAP tunneling is setup correctly. Also one of my colleagues is also able to ssh using cloud sdk from his mac.

I believe there could be something wrong with my cloud sdk setup but I am not sure.

Edit: I tried executing the command with verbosity:

```
gcloud compute ssh --verbosity=debug instance-name
```

And looking at the output, I think something might be wrong with my web socket. Maybe my laptop's firewall settings are prohibitting it. Although I am not sure about it:

```
gcloud compute ssh --verbosity=debug instance-name
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.compute.ssh] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug", [USER@]INSTANCE: "instance-name"]
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): compute.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /batch/compute/v1 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /batch/compute/v1 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
External IP address was not found; defaulting to using IAP tunneling.
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oslogin.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://oslogin.googleapis.com:443 "GET /v1/users/myid@some-org.com/loginProfile?alt=json&projectId=myproject-id HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO: Using OS Login user [myid_someorg_com] instead of default user [sahil]
DEBUG: SSH Known Hosts File [/Users/sahil/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts] could not be opened: Unable to read file [/Users/sahil/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/sahil/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts'
DEBUG: Running command [/usr/bin/ssh -t -i /Users/sahil/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o CheckHostIP=no -o HostKeyAlias=compute.5622012345678901234 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/Users/sahil/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts -o ProxyCommand /Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bundledpythonunix/bin/python3 /Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py compute start-iap-tunnel instance-name %p --listen-on-stdin --project=myproject-id --zone=us-central1-a --verbosity=debug -o ProxyUseFdpass=no myid_someorg_com@compute.5622012345678901234].
DEBUG: Executing command: ['/usr/bin/ssh', '-t', '-i', '/Users/sahil/.ssh/google_compute_engine', '-o', 'CheckHostIP=no', '-o', 'HostKeyAlias=compute.5622012345678901234', '-o', 'IdentitiesOnly=yes', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'UserKnownHostsFile=/Users/sahil/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts', '-o', 'ProxyCommand /Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bundledpythonunix/bin/python3 /Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py compute start-iap-tunnel instance-name %p --listen-on-stdin --project=myproject-id --zone=us-central1-a --verbosity=debug', '-o', 'ProxyUseFdpass=no', 'myid_someorg_com@compute.5622012345678901234']
DEBUG: Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud']
DEBUG: Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'beta']
DEBUG: Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'compute']
DEBUG: Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'compute', 'start_iap_tunnel']
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel] with arguments: [--listen-on-stdin: "True", --project: "myproject-id", --verbosity: "debug", --zone: "us-central1-a", INSTANCE_NAME: "instance-name", INSTANCE_PORT: "22"]
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): compute.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /batch/compute/v1 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: credentials type for _GetAccessTokenCallback is [<googlecloudsdk.core.credentials.google_auth_credentials.UserCredWithReauth object at 0x1104a3f10>].
DEBUG: Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO: Connecting with URL ['wss://tunnel.cloudproxy.app/v4/connect?project=myproject-id&zone=us-central1-a&instance=instance-name&interface=nic0&port=22']
DEBUG: Error during WebSocket processing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/websocket/_app.py", line 254, in run_forever
    proxy_type=proxy_type)
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/websocket/_core.py", line 223, in connect
    options.pop('socket', None))
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/websocket/_http.py", line 120, in connect
    sock = _open_socket(addrinfo_list, options.sockopt, options.timeout)
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/websocket/_http.py", line 189, in _open_socket
    raise error
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/websocket/_http.py", line 172, in _open_socket
    sock.connect(address)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
INFO: Error during WebSocket processing:
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

INFO: Client closed connection from [stdin].
DEBUG: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Error while connecting [[Errno 1] Operation not permitted].
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 982, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/compute/start_iap_tunnel.py", line 129, in Run
    iap_tunnel_helper.Run()
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/compute/iap_tunnel.py", line 633, in Run
    self._RunReceiveLocalData(_StdinSocket(), 'stdin')
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/compute/iap_tunnel.py", line 498, in _RunReceiveLocalData
    store.LoadIfEnabled(use_google_auth=True)))
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/compute/iap_tunnel.py", line 466, in _InitiateWebSocketConnection
    new_websocket.InitiateConnection()
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/iap_tunnel_websocket.py", line 132, in InitiateConnection
    self._WaitForOpenOrRaiseError()
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/iap_tunnel_websocket.py", line 350, in _WaitForOpenOrRaiseError
    raise ConnectionCreationError(error_msg)
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.compute.iap_tunnel_websocket.ConnectionCreationError: Error while connecting [[Errno 1] Operation not permitted].
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Error while connecting [[Errno 1] Operation not permitted].
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
DEBUG: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 982, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/compute/ssh.py", line 306, in Run
    force_connect=properties.VALUES.ssh.putty_force_connect.GetBool())
  File "/Users/sahil/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/util/ssh/ssh.py", line 1313, in Run
    raise CommandError(args[0], return_code=status)
googlecloudsdk.command_lib.util.ssh.ssh.CommandError: [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Comment: 1) Check that you have permission to create a tunnel (roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor). 2) What is the result from this command: `gcloud beta compute start-iap-tunnel VM_INSTANCE --zone ZONE` 3) If you can start the tunnel, check that the user and SSH key pair are correct.

Comment: Also... You shouldn't need the `user@` prefix as it will default to the current user. Are you credentialed as the same user on Cloud Shell as locally? `gcloud config get-value core/account` or `gcloud auth list --format="value(account)" --filter=status=ACTIVE`. Lastly, does the firewall rule permit your host's IP?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I do have tunnelResourceAccessor permission. Here is the response that I am getting:
`Picking local unused port [12345].
Testing if tunnel connection works.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.start-iap-tunnel) While checking if a connection can be made: Error while connecting [[Errno 1] Operation not permitted].`
I also tried without user@ but I get the same error.

I tried executing the command with verbosity and I am updating the question with its output.

Comment: I've also verified that my id in local is same as on cloud shell.

Comment: You do not have permissions required to create the tunnel: `Operation not permitted`

Comment: @JohnHanley, but if that was the case then shouldn't I also not have been able to do it through cloud shell?

Here is the output that I get when using the cloud shell:

External IP address was not found; defaulting to using IAP tunneling.
Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported.
Enter passphrase for key '/home/xxxx/.ssh/google_compute_engine':

Comment: The credentials that Cloud Shell is using might not be the same credentials that `gcloud` is configured with. Cloud Shell will be using the same credentials that you log in to Google via the browser. For the CLI  `gcloud auth list`.

Comment: `gcloud auth list` gives the same account on both cli and cloud shell. Moreover, `gcloud auth login` was used to login to CLI and access was provided using the user logged into the browser.

Comment: If you are using the same credentials on Cloud Shell and your Mac, then you have a problem with your Mac or your network. Do you have a firewall configured that blocks connections? Are you using a supported OS version? There are many possibilities. Investigate your system and compare it to the system your colleague is using that can connect.

Comment: @sahil Jain, can you please confirm whether issue resolved with solution provided by John in above comments.

Comment: @Nikhil, John has actually concluded what I suspected originally. But I haven't reached the root cause yet.

Comment: @Sahil Jain , for root cause you can refer document in which you will get details on error and respective solutions.   https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh